# Yii2 php, ayuda en el modelo

Tags: php, yii2

Buenas,
Tengo la columna, de codigo y en yii si uno le pone 0 luego del nombre de la otra tabla jala la información... pero no le puedo hacer el search, que tengo programar en el modelo??

```
use yii\helpers\Url;
```

return [

```
 [
    'class'=>'\kartik\grid\DataColumn',
    'attribute'=>'codigo0.NombreComercial',
],
```

Comment: fijate en esta solucion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36175084/yii2-gridview-relation-data-search-for-all-column

Comment: tambien te puede servir los escenarios 1 y 2 de esta pagina http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/621/filter-sort-by-calculated-related-fields-in-gridview-yii-2-0/#hh6

Answer (score 0):

Esta porcion de codigo te puede servir para crear una lista desplegable, con todos tus comercios. 
Solo queda que le modifiques por los nombres de atributo de tu modelo.

```
[
    'class'    => '\kartik\grid\DataColumn',
    'attribute'=> 'rucprove',
    'value'    => 'rucprove0.nomprove',
    'filter'   => \yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map(
                        app\models\Proveedor::find()
                             ->orderBy('nomprove')->asArray()
                             ->all(), 
                             'ruc', 'nomprove'), 
],
```